# Cannot open TIFF file due to missing codec

Tags: raster, gdal, r, installation

I am trying to rasterize a tif file by doing this: newData <- raster("file.tif"). However, when I run it, it says that it "Cannot open TIFF file due to missing codec". Upon looking online, it seems like the solution to this problem is to either update or install libtiff. I'm on Windows. How do I install libtiff into RStudio?

Things I tried:
I downloaded libtiff-0.4.2.tar, and am trying to install into my RStudio via install.packages("libtiff-0.4.2.tar", repos = NULL, type = "binary"). However it gives me this error

```
Warning in install.packages :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open compressed file 'libtiff-0.4.2.tar/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection
```

I also did install.packages("tiff"), library ("tiff") in RStudio.

I also installed it in Anaconda via "conda install -c anaconda libtiff" but as my Anaconda is synced up with Python, it didn't do anything for R. Is there a way to do the same thing but in Command Prompt/Powershell for R? Sorry, I'm all very new to this and unfortunately have a deadline coming up soon

Comment: I've added the "R" tag - that might help people find this question.